# Adding object-file dependencies

Tags: cmake, ninja

I have a CMake project. For some reason (that I won't say here, but which I can provide upon request), I need some object files that are part of the same library to be compiled before others. Specifically:

- `FILES` is a list of source files
- `file_a.c` is a member of `FILES`
- `file_d.c` is a member of `FILES`
- `file_a.o` MUST exist on disk before `file_d.c` is compiled

This is what I have now:

```
 set_source_files_properties(
   file_a.c
   PROPERTIES
   OBJECT_OUTPUTS file_a.o
   )

 set_source_files_properties(
   file_d.c
   PROPERTIES
   OBJECT_DEPENDS file_a.o
   )
```

This works well for Makefiles, but it doesn't appear to play nice with Ninja; I get a circular dependency error and complaints about multiple rules.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to declare dependencies between object files. If there are files that have a dependency, break them out into a separate library with `add_library` and then declare the dependency with `add_dependencies` and `target_link_libraries`. There is no extra cost for doing this.

Particularly, consider looking at [Object Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library).