# Copy compilation/linking settings from project in CMake object library?

Tags: cmake

I'm in a similar situation to [Adding object-file dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028473/adding-object-file-dependencies) where it is mentioned:

> ... I need some object files that are part of the same library to be compiled before others.
>
> Don't try to declare dependencies between object files. If there are files that have a dependency, break them out into a separate library with add_library and then declare the dependency with add_dependencies and target_link_libraries. There is no extra cost for doing this. Particularly, consider looking at Object Libraries.

I tried to implement this in my original project, where I'm working with a massive CMakeLists.txt file, where include & linker paths may be conditionally inserted or removed, and I failed. In essence, that CMakeLists.txt file would looks like this simplified:

```
project(MY_PROGRAM C CXX ASM)

set(MY_PROGRAM_sources
        main.c
        file_one.c
        file_two.c
        )

add_executable(MY_PROGRAM ${MY_PROGRAM_sources})

target_include_directories(MY_PROGRAM PRIVATE
        ${CUSTOM_PATH}/src/custom/include
        ...
        )

add_compile_options(-Wall
        -Wno-format
        ...
        )
        
target_link_libraries(MY_PROGRAM
        somelib1
        somelib2
        )
```

This builds fine, using Unix Makefiles.

Now, I've tried to extract file_one and file_two objects like this:

```
project(MY_PROGRAM C CXX ASM)

set(MY_PROGRAM_sources
        main.c
        #file_one.c
        #file_two.c
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:SEPFILE_OBJS>
        )

add_library(SEPFILE_OBJS OBJECT
  file_one.c
  file_two.c
)

add_executable(MY_PROGRAM ${MY_PROGRAM_sources})

target_include_directories(MY_PROGRAM PRIVATE
        ${CUSTOM_PATH}/src/custom/include
        ...
        )

add_compile_options(-Wall
        -Wno-format
        ...
        )
        
target_link_libraries(MY_PROGRAM
        somelib1
        somelib2
        )
```

`cmake` passes fine here, but when I hit `make`, there is breakage as soon as `file_one.c` starts compiling:

```
...
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/SEPFILE_OBJS.dir/file_one.c.obj
In file included from C:/tmp/file_one.c:14:
C:/tmp/file_one.h:19:10: fatal error: ExoticHeader.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <ExoticHeader.h>
```

Clearly, the SEPFILE_OBJS library did not inherit the include libraries nor other compilation/linker settings from the MY_PROGRAM executable.

I could probably repeat all target_* lines for SEPFILE_OBJS - but that looks quite unmanageable, plus my original CMakeLists.txt is huge, and I'd like to avoid that kind of work.

So is there a way to say to CMake "keep the same compilation and linker settings as in executable for MY_PROGRAM, also for the object library SEPFILE_OBJS"?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759647/how-to-get-include-directories-from-a-target-for-use-in-add-custom-target

Comment: With use of `get_property`/`set_property` commands, you may try to copy properties like `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `COMPILE_OPTIONS`, `LINK_LIBRARIES`, etc. from MY_PROGRAM to SEPFILE_OBJS. The set of properties with "compiler and linker settings" is quite small, so it shouldn't be a problem to list them. Probably, instead of copying you could use "symlinks" via generator expressions: `set_target_properties(SEPFILE_OBJS PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES $<TARGET_PROPERTY:MY_PROGRAM,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the way around. I would first define a library section, including `file_one.c` and `file_two.c`, and then a main executable section, which would link against this library target.

I would also follow something along the lines below for a directory structure (ideally, I would put the source files within a `src` directory):

```
/ MY_PROGRAM
|- include
|   \- MY_PROGRAM
|       |- file_one.h
|       \- fine_two.h
|- file_one.c
|- file_two.c
|- main.c
\- CMakeLists.txt
```

1. Put your header files in an `include/${PROJECT_NAME}` folder, and set an `include_dir` var pointing to it.

```
set(include_dir ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

2. Define the list of library and application sources:

```
set(lib_sources
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file_one.c"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file_two.c"
)
set(app_sources
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp"
)
```

3. Library section. Define a `lib_MY_PROGRAM` target, and set the include directories, compile options, and link libraries for it. Notice it's better to use the `target_...` specific commands than the more general ones, such as `add_compile_options`:

```
add_library(lib_${PROJECT_NAME} ${lib_sources})
target_include_directories(lib_${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${include_dir}>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
)
target_include_directories(lib_${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PUBLIC
    ${CUSTOM_PATH}/src/custom/include
)
target_compile_options(lib_${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    -Wall
    -Wno-format
)
target_link_libraries(lib_${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    somelib1
    somelib2
)
```

4. Main binary section:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${app_sources})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${include_dir}>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
)
target_compile_options(lib_${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    -Wall
    -Wno-format
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE lib_${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Why list(APPEND app_sources ${lib_sources})? Doesn't this build the lib sources twice, once in the library and once in the application target?

Comment: Ooops, many thanks for noticing! That line is not needed. Fixed.